# I'm trying to get Data from Server but its not getting into collection view: please have a look

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        getDataFromJSON()
        
        let numberOfItemsPerRow:CGFloat = 2
        let spacingBetweenCells:CGFloat = 25
        
        let totalSpacing = (2 * 10) + ((numberOfItemsPerRow - 1) * spacingBetweenCells) //Amount of total spacing in a row
        
        if let collection = self.collectionView{
            let width = (collection.bounds.width - totalSpacing)/numberOfItemsPerRow
            return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
        }else{
            return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        }
    }
```

I'm calling server inside the colletion view method but still won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove that getDataFromJSON() call from the sizeForItemAt method, and place it to your ViewController's viewWillAppear() method.

If you are about to download data from the server it will be asynchronous. It means your app has to wait until it's finished downloading, and then reload the displaying of your Collection View. Or any other view which are consuming the downloaded data.

So in concept:

1. start downloading the data in viewWillAppear(), or in viewDidLoad() depending on your client's needs
2. after the download finished, reload the collectionView and any other view which are consuming the data which is just downloaded

Comment: You need to make really sure about every part. Is the data really downloaded? Is it converted to structs/classes correctly? Did the refresh happen AFTER the download and parsing of the JSON finished? Try to debug it.